# How to find Code Coverage of a C project in KEIL IDE?

Tags: c, microcontroller, keil

I am using Keil uvison 5 Evaluation version. After Run/Stop the code in debug mode it shows 0% coverage for each function in my C project.

[image]

What steps need to be followed for getting the code coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, common debuggers are unsuitable to trace code execution.
Tracing user code avaliable only with UlinkPro debugger (and also without real hardware - in Keil simulator).

More information: http://www2.keil.com/coresight/#etm